# Thread isn't Starting

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm new to c# and Multithreading. I have this code to getting started with Multithreading but clock tick isn't getting started. What's wrong with this code? No error occurs because its a logical error I guess. Any help would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
namespace Implementing_Databases
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            picturebox1.Location=new Point(0,20);
            pictureBox2.Location = new Point(0, 60);
        }
        int B1 = 0;
        int B2 = 0;
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread Th1 = new Thread(Go1);
            Thread Th2 = new Thread(Go2);
            Th1.Start();
            Th2.Start();

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            picturebox1.Left = B1;
            B1 += 5;

        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            pictureBox2.Left = B2;
            B2 += 5;

        }
        void Go1()
        {
            timer1.Start();
        }
        void Go2()
        {
            timer2.Start();
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any timers declared?

Comment: I used the timer from a toolbox. I guess that is declared at background?

Comment: Why don't you just call `timer1.Start()` from the `Form1_Load` method. Wrapping it in the `Thread` achives nothing in this case.

Comment: This looks weird. Could you explain what are you trying to achieve? [Winforms timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) is not designer to work in multi-threaded environment. To make it working you have to invoke `Start`. But why would you want that? Again, why do you create 2 threads, where each starts timer in turn?

Comment: I know I can do that and that will move these two pictureboxes simultaneously but I want to do that using multithreading.

Comment: Start Multithreading from [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try declaring threads as properties of form rather than declaring them as local function variables. Because otherwise they may be collected by GC straight away after Load handler exits.

Secondly, UI not updating may be due to the fact that you cannot update UI data from non GUI thread. See InvokeRequired/Invoke feature of WinForms programming. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx for more details

Comment: Tick callbacks will be invoked by timer threads. Which aren't GUI

Comment: I have tried declaring the threads as Form's property. Still no gain.

Comment: If you try to debug the solution. Can you see values being incremented?

Comment: Also could you please show is the code how timers are declared and configured. You may be having timer elapse period set up as infinity for example. Thats why it is not ticking